# How to make pixels arrays from RGB image without losing its spatial information in python?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I am wondering is there any workaround to convert RGB images to pixel vectors without losing its spatial information in python. As far as I know, I can read the images and do transformation for images to pixel vectors. I am not sure doing this way still preserve images' spatial information in pixel vectors. How can I make this happen for making pixel vectors from RGB image?

**my attempt**:

I tried as follow but I am not sure how to make

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

image = plt.imread('dog.jpg')
im = image/255.0
print(im.shape) #(32, 32, 3)
pixels = im.reshape(im.shape[0]*im.shape[1], im.shape[2])
```

but I want to make sure how to make pixel vectors from RGB images without losing pixel order and its spatial information. How to make this happen? any thoughts?

I think maybe `numpy` might have functions to do this. Can anyone point me how to do this with `numpy`?

**graphic illustration**:

here is simple graphic illustration of making pixel vectors from RGB images:

[image: make pixel vectors from RGB image]

as this diagram shows, we have RGB images with shape of (4,4,3) which needs to make pixel vectors without losing its spatial information and pixel orders then combine pixel vectors from each channel (Red, Green, Blue) as pixel matrix or dataframe. I am curious how to get this done in python?

**goal**:

I want to make pixel vectors from RGB images so resulted pixel vectors needs to be expanded with taylor expansion. Can anyone point me out how to make this happen?

Comment: you can use `rgb = np.dstack((r,g,b))` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are You just trying to reshape each channel to a vector and then joining them horizontally? That's what I understood from the graphic illustration and the way i would do it is something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = plt.imread('monkey.png')
image = image / 255.0
red = image[:,:,0]
green = image[:,:,1]
blue = image[:,:,2]

def to_vector(matrix):
    result = []
    for i in range(matrix.shape[1]):
        result = np.vstack(matrix[:,i])
    return result

red = to_vector(red)
green = to_vector(green)
blue = to_vector(blue)

vector = np.hstack((red,green,blue))
```

Comment: it is not just reshaping but make sure while making pixel vectors from RGB image, I want to preserve its pixel order and spatial information. also using `np.hstack()` won't get my expected pixel arrays

Comment: Maybe after edit it is more useful? Now I take each column of the channel and make a vertical stack, I think it's easy now to get the coordinates of each pixel.

Comment: @Grobocop12 Consider using ravel() - your to_vector() is essentially a special case of that

Comment: @AlexI thanks for heads up. Do you mind to share your thoughts if you have better approach? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your original attempt was almost a full solution - maybe actually a full solution, depending on what the idea is.

```
print(im.shape) #(32, 32, 3)
pixels = im.reshape(im.shape[0]*im.shape[1], im.shape[2]) # this is exactly correct
print(pixels.shape) #(1024,3)
reds = pixels[:, 0] #just as an example for where things end up in the result
pixels_channelfirst = np.moveaxis(pixels, 1, 0) # if you want the first axis to be channels
print(pixels.shape) #(3, 1024)
reds = pixels[0, :]
```

"I want to preserve its pixel order and spatial information" - this does that already!  Add one non-zero pixel to a zero image and plot where it goes, if you have doubts. np.hstack in the other answer does as well.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why you mentioned of using `np.ravel()` in below comment? what that efficient the attempt of @Grobocop12 from your attempt? I am just want to know the difference for learning purpose. Thanks a lot